# working with generic lifetime managers in unity config section

Tags: asp.net, configuration, unity-container, lifetime

I have the following generic lifetime manager

```
    public class RequestLifetimeManager<T> : LifetimeManager, IDisposable
    {
    public override object GetValue()
    {
        return HttpContext.Current.Items[typeof(T).AssemblyQualifiedName];
    }
    public override void RemoveValue()
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Items.Remove(typeof(T).AssemblyQualifiedName);
    }
    public override void SetValue(object newValue)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Items[typeof(T).AssemblyQualifiedName] = newValue;
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        RemoveValue();
    }
}
```

How do I reference this in the unity config section. Creating a type alias

```
<typeAlias alias="requestLifeTimeManager`1" type=" UI.Common.Unity.RequestLifetimeManager`1,  UI.Common" />
```

and specifying it as a lifetime manager

```
   <types>
    <type type="[interface]" mapTo="[concretetype]" >
      <lifetime type="requestLifeTimeManager`1"  />
    </type>
  </types>
```

causes the following error

```
Cannot create an instance of UI.Common.Unity.RequestLifetimeManager`1[T] because Type.ContainsGenericParameters is true.
```

How do you reference generic lifetime managers ?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use the type aliases when referencing generic type, you have to reference the types explicitly. The following now works

```
    <container name="defaultContainer">
  <types>
    <type type="ILayoutManager" mapTo="LayoutManager" >
      <lifetime  type="Publishing.UI.Common.Unity.RequestLifetimeManager`1[[Publishing.BLL.Managers.LayoutManager, Publishing.BLL, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c02010e20f60e4d2]], Publishing.UI.Common, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c02010e20f60e4d2"  />
    </type>
  </types>
</container>
```